# Mockito :Spring JPA Dao layer testing

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Junit test for my spring application and the class under test is DAO class. I am using JPA for my persistance . I am unable to find a proper example of testing spring JPA dao class with mockito. Below is what i have tried so far.

DOA class

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractAppDao<User, Integer> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entitymanager;


    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.test.UserDaoImpl.lcass");

    public UserDaoImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }


    @Override
    public String createUser(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, Set<String> assignUserGroups,
            String emailId, String approverEmailId, String loggedInUserName) throws Exception {

        User user = null;
        try {
            user = new User();
            User approver=new User();
            user.setLoginUserId(userName);
            user.setFirstName(firstName);
            user.setLastName(lastName);
            user.setEmailId(emailId);
            user.setNotifyViaEmail("Y");
            user.setContactNo(220);
            if (approverEmailId != null) {
                approver=getUserByEmail(approverEmailId);
                if (approver.getUserId()!= 0) {
                    user.setApproverId(approver.getUserId());
                }
            }
            user.setLoginRetryCount(10);
            user.setActiveStatus(PDPConstants.PENDING_STATUS);
            user.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

            save(user);
            return "User  is created successfully";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Junit Code So far

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDaoTest  {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entitymanager;

    @InjectMocks
    UserDaoImpl  userDao;



    @Test
    public void createPdpUser() throws Exception {
        User user = null;
        try {

            user = new User();
            User approver=new User();
            user.setLoginUserId("test");
            user.setFirstName("firstName");
            user.setLastName("lastName");
            user.setEmailId("am");
            user.setNotifyViaEmail("Y");
            user.setContactNo(220);
            String approverEmailId;
            user.setApproverId(22);
            user.setLoginRetryCount(10);
            user.setActiveStatus("PA");
            user.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
            userDao.save(user);
            Mockito.verify(userDao.getEntityManager(),Mockito.atLeast(1)).merge(Mockito.anyObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I finally modified the junit code and was able to run the test case

Comment: Your test should not extend the class you want to test. Create a dedicated test class, than create an instance of the class you want to test. You can consider using the InjectMock annotation.

Comment: I am not extend the class i am testing i am extending an abstract class thats it i can remove i dont think that should cause issue

Comment: Ok its a different class, but its a dao too. You problem goes down to that getEntityManager returns the EntityManager of your abstract class and not your mock.

Comment: @mh-dev i was able to run test case thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code in question please review

Comment: Seems a lot better. You can remove the try catch since you have throws exception anyways and there's nothing wrong about this.